# How can I create a dispatch table that creates different types of objects

Tags: dart

If I define a bunch of classes:

```
class A  {
  final List<int> value;
  A(this.value);
  static make(List<int> value) => new A(value);
}
// more class defs here
class Z  {
  final List<String> value;
  Z(this.value);
  static make(List<String> value) => new A(value);
}
```

Then the following doesn't work, because Type has no methods

```
Map<int, Type> typeMap = {0: A, 25: Z};
new typeMap[0]([1, 2, 3])
```

But the following does work. Although, it takes lots of extra work to create the static make methods.

```
Map<int, Function> funcMap = {0: A.make, 25: Z.make};
funcMap[0]([1, 2, 3])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable or `dart:mirrors` if it's not for the browser (dart2js with mirrors can cause code bloat for the resulting JS output file).

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

There is a syntax for converting a constructor to a function, but it isn't implemented everywhere yet, and it's likely to change in the future, so I don't recommend using it.

The alternative to having a `make` or `create` function is to write that function inline in the map:
`dart
Map<int, Function> funcMap = {0: (v) => new A(v), 25: (v) => new Z(v)};`

Whether that's more or less readable is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks.  What is the syntax for converting a constructor to a function.  I would much rather do Foo(x, y) than new Foo(x, y).